# Event shift key in combination

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard-shortcuts, shift, ctrl

I need undo and redo in javascript.

ctrl + z = undo

ctrl + shift + z = redo

In the code described below, undo works normally but redo does not work. I noticed if it is shift.key alon then it works, if combined with others (shift.key + ctrl.key or "z") it doesn't work. Why.., or am I wrong somewhere in the code?

```js
function isKeyPressedUndo(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    x.innerHTML = "The UNDO key was pressed!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "The UNDO key was NOT pressed!";
  }
}

function isKeyPressedRedo(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    x.innerHTML += "The REDO key was pressed!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML += "The REDO key was NOT pressed!";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="isKeyPressedUndo(event), isKeyPressedRedo(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging 101: If an `if` statement fails, **log the values** you are testing with it.

When the shift key is pressed `event.key` is an upper-case `Z` not a lower-case `z`.

```js
function isKeyPressedUndo(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    x.innerHTML = "The UNDO key was pressed!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "The UNDO key was NOT pressed!";
  }
}

function isKeyPressedRedo(event) {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  console.log([event.shiftKey, event.ctrlKey, event.key]);
  if (event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    x.innerHTML += "The REDO key was pressed!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML += "The REDO key was NOT pressed!";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="isKeyPressedUndo(event), isKeyPressedRedo(event)">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If I add a upper-case Z, then it works, thank you. But the following problem arose, if I turn on Caps Lock on the keyboard then nothing works, how can I enable it to work if Caps Lock is on or off?

Answer (score 3):

event.key on shift is uppercase!

```js
const x = document.getElementById("demo");
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log("ctrl",event.ctrlKey,"shift",event.shiftKey,"key",event.key)
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    if (event.key.toLowerCase() === 'z') {
      if (event.shiftKey) x.innerHTML = "The REDO key was pressed!";
      else x.innerHTML += "The UNDO key was pressed!";
    } else {
      if (event.key === 'y') x.innerHTML = "The REDO key was pressed!";
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" autocomplete="off">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the shift key is pressed, the key becomes `Z` (capital z).

It is generally [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) to use inline event handlers. Here's a somewhat simplified snippet, using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
document.addEventListener(`keydown`, handle);

function handle(event) {
  if (event.target.id === `keyTest`) {
    // toLowerCase for shift and/or caps lock
    const isZ = event.key.toLowerCase() === `z`;
    const [isUndo, isRedo] = [
      event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey && isZ,
      event.shiftKey && event.ctrlKey && isZ ];
    
    document.querySelector(`#demo`).innerHTML = isUndo ?
      `The UNDO key was pressed!` 
      : isRedo ? `The REDO key was pressed!` : `Regular input &hellip;`
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="keyTest">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: How do I make this to work when caps lock is on or off?

Comment: Use `event.key.toLowerCase`, see edited answer